# Running a dpkg installer to install deb in wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I want to do an automatic installer for deb installation. Manually we are using:

```
dpkg -i --force-overwrite xxx.tar .
```

But how to do it in wxpython? I have GUI ready and with 1 click on button it has to run
that command. any suggestions? 
Along with that I do not know how to save dependencies file  in other directory.

Comment: I don't understand your comment about "dependencies file". Can you clarify (or maybe create a separate question)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can shell out from python to execute arbitrary shell commands. See [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html). But you will need the user running your program to have sufficient sudo rights to install the package.

Comment: do you have any code? Can you suggest syntax related to this?

Comment: You should find examples on the page I linked to.

Answer (score 1):

I used Subprocess.call().. and its worked fine for me.